# Angular Material: не открывается диалогвоое окно после выбора фильтра

Tags: typescript, angular

открываю страницу на которой есть фильтры, открываю окно создания айтема - закрываю, выбираю фильтр - диалоговое окно больше не открывается.

Открывается диалогвое окно как компонента

```
  openDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogContentExampleDialog);

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
    });
  }
```

приблизительно так.
Если укого-то есть идеи - с радостью их прочитаю)

Comment: Кажется, первый абзац не нужен в вопросе. Уточните - у вас проблема в том, что  первая строка функции openDialog срабатывает успешно только для первого вызова метода openDialog?

Comment: диалог вызывается в любом случае, но после выбора фильтров на странице повторно диалоговое окно не открывается

Comment: диалог успешно открывается при первом вызову и при последующих если не выбирать фильтры после первого открытия (на страницы есть выпадающие списки для фильтрации